# Realm Runtime Error

Tags: try-catch, realm

I recently upgraded to Swift 2.0 and now I have been experiencing problems with realm.  Most recently, I am experiencing an issue where the app instantly crashes when it reaches the first occurrence of a "try! Realm()"  resulting in this error:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=io.realm Code=2 "open() failed: No such file or directory" 
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/XXXXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7299DF18-E7D5-4499-93DD-A5035FB48E67/data/Containers/Data/Application/BED64819-5895-407F-9E90-9888741E24EB/Documents/default.realm,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=open() failed: No such file or directory, Error
>   Code=2}:  file
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.0.59/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 50 (lldb)

I saw one other post somewhat related to this, but it did not help because I am not trying to call the path directly, it is just throwing this error.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `try!` in Swift, you're choosing to ignore errors that you could otherwise recover from.

In this case, the `Realm` initializer is marked as `throws`. Here's an excerpt from Realm's docs on [Error Handling](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#error-handling):

> Like any disk IO operation, creating a Realm instance could sometimes fail if resources are constrained. In practice, this can only happen the first time a Realm instance is created on a given thread. Subsequent accesses to a Realm from the same thread will reuse a cached instance and will always succeed.
>
> To handle errors when first accessing a Realm on a given thread, use Swift’s built-in error handling mechanism:

```
do {
  let realm = try Realm()
} catch let error as NSError {
  // handle error
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened to me when I manually deleted an object from Realm via Realm browser.
Here are my two cents: Deleting realm.lock and other log files and relaunching an app worked for me. Take a look at the screenshot:

[image]